# How to find length of the sides of a triangle given the ratio of the sines of the angles?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, ratio

Consider $\triangle ABC$. 
Let $\dfrac{\sin A}{\sin B} = \dfrac56$ and 
$\dfrac{\sin B}{\sin C} = \dfrac45$.

Find $\dfrac{\vert AC\vert\cdot \vert AB\vert}{\vert BC\vert}$.

If there is no definite answer, express in terms of one of the sides.

Comment: Do you know the sine rule? That helps. But the ratio of sines is the same for a whole family of similar triangles, whilst the expression you have to find depends on the size of the triangle, so the value will not be determined by the information you have given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines): $\dfrac {\sin A}{|BC|} = \dfrac{\sin B}{|AC|} = \dfrac{\sin C}{|AB|}=D$ ($D$ is the diameter of the circumcircle)
we see that \begin{align}\dfrac{\sin A}{\sin B} =\dfrac{\vert BC\vert}{\vert AC\vert}= \dfrac56\\\dfrac{\sin B}{\sin C} =\dfrac{\vert AC\vert}{\vert AB\vert}= \dfrac45\end{align}

So $\displaystyle \dfrac{\vert AC\vert\cdot \vert AB\vert}{\vert BC\vert} = \vert AB\vert\frac 65$

Answer (score 0):

From the Law of Sinus, we know that:

$\frac{\text{sin}(A)}{\text{sin}(B)}=\frac{|BC|}{|AC|}=\frac{5}{6}$

$\frac{\text{sin}(B)}{\text{sin}(C)}=\frac{|AC|}{|AB|}=\frac{4}{5}$

$\frac{\text{sin}(A)}{\text{sin}(C)}=\frac{|BC|}{|AB|}=\frac{2}{3}$

From this we get:

$6|BC|-5|AC|=0$

$5|AC|-4|AB|=0$

$3|BC|-2|AB|=0$

We can solve these equations with linear algebra:

$$
\left[
\matrix
{
6& -5&  0 & 0 \\
0&  5& -4 & 0 \\
3&  0& -2 & 0 
}
\right]\rightarrow\left[
\matrix
{
1& -\frac{5}{6}&  0 & 0 \\
0&  1& -\frac{4}{5} & 0 \\
0& 0&  0 & 0 
}
\right]
$$

Therefore, if t=|BC|, the solutions is given by:

$\left[
\matrix
{
|BC| \\
|AC| \\
|AB|
}
\right]=t\left[
\matrix
{
1 \\
\frac{5}{6} \\
\frac{2}{3}
}
\right]$

And the desired product is:

$\frac{5}{9t}= \frac{5}{9|BC|}$

Comment: Yeah... gebruikers way is a lot easier.. better luck next time i guess :)